# ASP.NET MVC models that order table data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an MVC project.  There is a default view and controller.  There is a model that has been expanded to cover two real tables and a view (db view).  That view and at least one of the tables need to be displayed AFTER sorting the data. I only see "simple" examples of creating models online; I'm not sure what words to search on. So, I have a class in its own file that defines the columns in a db-view

```
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace XYZ_dbo.Models {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
        using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;

        [Table("dbo.DockItemsByDept")]
        public partial class DockItemsByDept
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Dept { get; set; }
            public int Code { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I have a model definition that references this class:

```
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace XYZ.Models
    {
        public partial class XYZModel : DbContext
        {
            public XYZModel()
                : base("name=XYZModel")
            {
            }

            public virtual DbSet<DockItemsByDept> DockItemsByDept { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<DockItemsByDept>()
                    .Property(e => e.Id);
                modelBuilder.Entity<DockItemsByDept>()
                    .Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
                modelBuilder.Entity<DockItemsByDept>()
                    .Property(e => e.Dept);
                modelBuilder.Entity<DockItemsByDept>()
                    .Property(e => e.Code);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can go into the `index.cshtml` view and say

```
    @model IEnumerable<ITG_Calendar_Reservations.Models.DockItemsByDept>

    <div class="content">
        @foreach (var log in Model)
        {
            <p>@log.Name</p>
        }
    </div>
```

but I just get the default ordering the DB generates.  I want this "view" data sorted by the `Code` field then the `Name` field but I have no idea where such an operation or filter should be applied. I *thought* this would be in the model but I'm not seeing where it should go and I'm not finding anything useful when I search for an answer.

Ideas?

Comment: Your `XYZModel` here isn't really a model, it's a context which serves to manage the state of the models between your program and the database.  You may want to call it `XYZContext`.  It may make things a little easier to comprehend.

Comment: uh, ok.  I'm not debating you on this at all.  Visual Studio called it a "Model" and gave it that name when it setup the initial DB connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 @foreach (var log in Model.OrderBy(m => m.Code).ThenBy(m => m.Name))
```

Alternatively, you can sort the model before you send it to the view.

Comment: Cool! thank you.  How do you sort before sending to the view?

Comment: Pretty much the same way, just move the ordering code to where you pull data from the database to populate Model. Although your *code* looks the same, the ordering will actually happen in the database which can be more efficient if you do it in a line like `myModel = db.DockItemsByDepts.OrderBy(m => m.Code).ThenBy(m => m.Name)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I must be thick but you said "move the ordering code to where you pull data from the database". I look at the code above and I don't see where that place is/should be.  It appears to all be happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Linq to order the output as desired

```
foreach (var log in Model.OrderBy(m => m.Code).ThenBy(m => m.Name))
```